# Can I delete StoreData found at /private/var/log/powermanagement/StoreData?

Tags: macos, logs

I had a problem backing-up my (mid-2007) iMac running El Capitan using SuperDuper. I sent SuperDuper the error log and they suggested that I delete StoreData found at `/private/var/log/powermanagement/StoreData`

Can I simply put StoreData in the trash and empty it? Will deleting the file cause any problems for my system? Do I need to re-create a blank StoreData file somehow? If so, what is the file extension?

Answer (score 1):

Answers to your questions as follows:

- Yes, you can safely remove the `/private/var/log/powermanagement/StoreData` file as suggested. If you're overly concerned about it, feel free to just make a copy of it first before trashing it.

  **Note:** You'll be prompted for an Admin password before being able to move it to Trash.
- No, deleting the file will not cause any problems for your system.
- No, you do not need to recreate the file.  It'll automatically be recreated again when needed. In fact, the system will most likely recreate it within a few minutes of you trashing it.